# Transferring Variables (C#)

Tags: c#, variables, conditional-statements

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int par = 3;
        int strokes = 4;
        int score;

        Console.Write("Enter Score ");

        par = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        strokes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        score = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        ***bool parse = int.TryParse(strokes, out score);***

        if (score < par) 
           Console.WriteLine("Score is below par.");
        else if (score > par)
           Console.WriteLine("Score is above par.");
        else if (score == par)
           Console.WriteLine("Score is equal to par.");
    }    
}
```

Hello, I am trying to have the value of strokes become the value of score so that when a user inputs how many strokes they made, it converts to score...  The code that I highlighted `bool parse = int.TryParse(strokes, out score);` worked before on another program.  However on this one it is telling me I cannot convert a string to an int.  Which I thought I did with:`strokes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

Please be nice! I am new to this.

Comment: You are trying to parse an `int`. `TryParse` expects a string. I would imagine you can remove the line entirely and it should work.

Comment: Given `strokes` and `score` are both `int`, why not just `strokes = score;` ?

Comment: Latoya Emmer, Please be nice - if you write some strange code (like `int.TryParse(int, out int)` ) be patient and explain why it is important to you.

Comment: It is an assignment. maybe I read it wrong? Here's the instructions: Use if, else if, and else statements to determine when a golf score is above, below or equal to par. Print the
message “score is below par” or “score is above par” or “score is equal to par” depending on your answer. Use
par and strokes as the variable names and set par=3 and strokes=4.
EXPECTED OUTPUT
The score is above par.

Comment: You can remove the parse line. Then remove the score variable and everything using it (it's not needed here logically and per your assignment). Then change the if statements to use `strokes` instead of `score` and it should work.

Comment: Ok so I deleted the parse line and everything that had to do with score but now I am receiving an error for line 20 which is: 'strokes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());'

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax problem as well as a semantic problem.  Firstly, you declared `strokes` as an `int`.

```
 int strokes = 4;
```

Then you assigned it (which is fine)

```
 strokes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Lastly, you are trying to parse it as an int, which it already is.

```
 bool parse = int.TryParse(strokes, out score);
```

Syntactically, `int.TryParse` expects a `string` parameter, where you are sending it an `int` parameter.  You can always refer to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on the method you are using for clarification.

However, semantically, you already have an `int`, and are trying to parse it as an `int`, which is wrong and redundant.  `TryParse` should be used when you have a string that you *believe* to be an `int`, but want to validate without throwing an exception.  In the case of this code, you could use `TryParse` on the user input to verify they have given you an `int`, rather than directly casting it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Convert.To..()` will throw FormatException if the input string is not convertible to the destination type. The thing you are doing wrong is that through  this line (`strokes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`) you are converting the input to an `integer` and again you are going for a Parse.

> **Note:**  The input to the [`Int32.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) should be a string and an integer variable as out param. in your case both are integers.

I suggest you the following way to do this in a better way:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int par = 3;
        int strokes = 4;
        int score;
        Console.Write("Enter Score ");
        if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out par))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("invalid input; conversion failed");
        }
        if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out strokes))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("invalid input; conversion failed");
        }
        if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out score))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("invalid input; conversion failed");
        }
        // Now you will get all values; so you can proceed
        if (score < par)
            Console.WriteLine("Score is below par.");
        else if (score > par)
            Console.WriteLine("Score is above par.");
        else if (score == par)
            Console.WriteLine("Score is equal to par.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering with the code ans using user input, I found the solution.

```
 {
        int par = 3;
        int strokes = 4;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Score ");
        strokes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (strokes < par)
            Console.WriteLine("Score is below par.");

            else if (strokes > par)
                Console.WriteLine("Score is above par.");

                    else if (strokes == par)
                      Console.WriteLine("Score is equal to par.");

    }
```